# Gitlab. Не могу подключиться по ssh

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, ssh-key, openssh

Помогите разобраться.

1. Установил gitlab.
2. Поставил Git на свой компьютер.
3. Создал приват ключ на своем компьютере при помощи - PuTTy Key Generator.
4. Вставил ключ в SSH Keys на сервере gitlab
5. Создал проект (закрытый)
6. Вставляю ссылку в remote: git@myserver:root/first-pr.git
7. Openssh запрашивает пароль и не один не походит.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: «Вставляю ссылку в remote» — о каком таком remote речь?

Comment: Вот сейчас пытаюсь через TortoiseGit.

Git -> remote.

Remote: original.

URL: git@myserver:root/first-pr.git.

Putty Key: aa.ppk.

Делаю Add.. Ввожу пароль root.

Ошибка.

git.exe fetch -v --progress "origin".

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.

git@myserver: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Ошибка была ssh клиенте.